# Plugin jQuery alterar atributos com $.extend

Tags: javascript, jquery

Criei um objeto em um plugin acima de `.fn`. Pois geralmente são criados dentro os objetos daí fazemos o seguinte:

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.tooltip = function(options) {

        var defaults = {
          'corDeFundo' : 'yellow'
        };

        var settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );

        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).css({ background: settings.corDeFundo });
        });

    }; 
})( jQuery );
```

Mas meu objeto, foi criado acima:

```
(function( $ ){
   var m = {
        "input"  : "outado",
        init:function(options){
            console.log(m.seletor);     
            return m.seletor;
        },//INIT FIM    
    }

   $.fn.input= function(method) {       

        var settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, method);

        console.log(m.seletor);
        return m.init.apply( this, arguments );


    }; 
})( jQuery );

$("div").input({
   input : "red"

})
```

Como faço para definir os atributos do objeto, pois para pegar faço assim dentro da função: `m.seletor`. Mas para alterar como que tenho que fazer?

**Correção:**
Bastava usar da seguinte maneira:

```
 var settings = $.extend( {}, m, method );
            console.log(settings.seletor)
```

**Meu problema mesmo é**: Como que faço para passar este objeto alterado para a função `INIT()`? Terei que criar outro objeto, ou o quê?

Comment: Olá. Onde está "m.seletor" não deveria ser "m.input"? Se bem entendi o que pretende é que o console.log desse o resultado de "red". É isso?

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem, vc quer utilizar as options dentro do plugin.

Para ilustrar alterei o seu código e inclui a funcionalidade de adicionar uma nova classe no elemento

```
    (function( $ ){
        $.fn.input = function(options) {
            //aqui são definidos os dados padrão
            var defaults = {
                "input"  : "outado"
            };
            //se foi passado algum item, atualiza o padrão...
            //esta variável fica disponível para todos aqui dentro
            options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            //aqui a função que vc deseja executar
            var init = function(target){
                //neste ponto podes realizar o que precisa com o seletor que foi passado como parametro
                //somente como um exemplo vou adicionar uma nova classe no item
                jQuery(target).addClass(options.input);
            };

            //inicializa...
            init(this);
        };
    })( jQuery );
```

para testar vc pode

```
jQuery("#teste").input({input:"nova-classe"});
```